# Looping through arrays and increasing counters in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-in-loop

So I am trying to loop through an array and increase a two counters based on the index in the array. The array has boolean values in it and the counters are for said boolean values. My implementation is error filled, so I am trying to figure out whether my logic is incorrect or my implementation is incorrect. So an extra pair of eyes would help

```
var numTrue = 0
var numFalse = 0
var boolArray = [true, true, false, true]

for index in boolArray.enumerate() {
  if index == false{
    numFalse++
  } else {
    numTrue++
  }
}

print("Count true: \(numTrue)")
print("Count false: \(numFalse)")
```

Comment: What errors to you get?

Comment: XCode is telling me there is an issue with the binary operator "==". So it doesn't seem to like my " if index == false" statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code does not compile because `enumerate` is returning you a `SequenceType` in form `(n, x)`.

Change your code to the following:

```
var numTrue = 0
var numFalse = 0
let boolArray = [true, true, false, true]

//We are interested in value, ignoring the index
for (_, value) in boolArray.enumerate()
{
    if value == false
    {
        numFalse++
    }
    else
    {
        numTrue++
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Count true: 3
Count false: 1
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I need to dedicate extra time to learning enumerations. I just learned enough to know it is how I could access the index of the array.

Answer (score 4):

Like [Unheilig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227834/unheilig) wrote enumarate is returning a sequenceType.

You can also remove the enumerate call, which in my opinion make the code in your case more readable like this:

```
var numTrue = 0
var numFalse = 0
var boolArray = [true, true, false, true]

for index in boolArray {
    if index == false{
        numFalse++
    } else {
        numTrue++
    }
}

print("Count true: \(numTrue)")
print("Count false: \(numFalse)")
```

**Edit 1: Quick-Help Doc**

For the next time If you have a similar problem or error popping up you can also use the Quick-Help Documentation by holding alt and hovering over the method than a questionmark appears and you can click on the method. A window will open with a description of the method and sometimes an example like in the case of enumerate(). See the screenshot below:

[image]

**Edit 2: Improved Solution**

Swift provides methods on collections in your case an array to reduce the amount of code.
In your case you can use the method filter() which returns a new array by filtering out elements from the array on which it's called. The only argument is a closure (read more about closures [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)) that returns a boolean and it will execute this closure once for each element in the array.
Swift automatically provides shorthand argument names to inline closures which can be used to refer to the values of the closure's arguments by the names `$0, $1, $2` and so on (from the documentation).

So in your case `$0` stands for each element beginning at index 0.

`count` returns the number of elements in you array, so in your case by using `filter` it only returns 3 because true appears 3 times. `trueCounter = 3`

For the `falseCounter` you can easily subtract the result of the trueCounter from `boolArray.count` which is `falseCounter = 4 - 3 -> 1`

```
var boolArray = [true, true, false, true]

let trueCounter = boolArray.filter({$0 == true}).count
let falseCounter = boolArray.count - trueCounter

print("Count true: \(trueCounter)") // Count true: 3
print("Count false: \(falseCounter)") // Count false: 1
```

Comment: I think your approach is the one I will try to work with. I want to learn more details on enumerations and this is a simpler approach a novice like myself.

Comment: @rowenarrow Great that I could also helped you. I edited my answer with a hint to the quick-help documentation. I think as you're a beginner it will help you a lot in future issues

Comment: FYI @rowenarrow, I've added an improved solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var numTrue = 0
var numFalse = 0
let boolArray = [true, true, false, true]

for index in boolArray {
    if index {
        numTrue += 1
    } else {
        numFalse += 1
    }
}

print("Count true: \(numTrue)")
print("Count false: \(numFalse)")
```

Comment: the "if index" is throwing a flag but this does remind me that I can use += 1

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have? I works perfectly here. Have you seen, I haver removed the `.enumerate()`?

Comment: 7.2.1 and now it seems to be working. I like your way as well but already accepted an answer. In your approach how is numTrue == true. I can't seem to figure the relationship?

Comment: `if index {` is the same as `if index == true {`. I flipped the cases to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some more swifty spice, here's a different approach.

```
numTrue = boolArray.filter{ $0 }.count
numFalse = boolArray.count - numTrue
```

It does have different runtime characteristics though (i.e. creates a new array on the filter operation) - so I'd not recommend it unconditionally.